# "Totally real" linear transformations

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, linear-algebra, differential-topology

Identify $\mathbb{C}^n$ with $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ via the equality $$(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n)=(x_1, \ldots, x_n, y_1, \ldots , y_n)$$
Where $z_j=x_j + iy_j$.

We call a linear invertible map $A: \mathbb{R}^{2n}\to \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ totally real if the image of every complex line is not a complex line (i.e a totally real plane). Equivalently, if $Gr(2,2n)$ denotes the Grassmannian of planes in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ then  $\mathbb{C}P(n-1)$ lives inside $Gr(2,2n)$, and $A$ being totally real means that $\mathbb{C}P(n-1)$ intersects its image
trivially. Note that the (real) dimension of $\mathbb{C}P(n-1)$ is half the dimension of $Gr(2,2n)$.

As an example, for $n=2$, the linear map $$B:(x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2)\to (-y_2
, x_1, y_1, -x_2)$$
Is totally real and satisfies $\det(B)=1$. Since $B$ is isotopic to identity through linear maps, then $B(\mathbb{C}P(1))$ is isotopic to $\mathbb{C}P(1)$ which shows that the self intersection number of $\mathbb{C}P(1)$ (inside $Gr(2,4)$) is zero.

Similarly, the previous example can be generalized to all $n=2k$ even.

My question: is it possible to find a totally real linear (invertible) transformation $A$ for $n\geq 3$ odd? (we allow $A$ to have negative determinant).

Note that if the self intersection number of $\mathbb{C}P(n-1)$ (inside $Gr(2,2n)$) is non-zero for $n$ odd, then $A$ cannot have positive determinant. But I don't know if this is the case and I would like also to know what is the self intersection number in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misreading but could you clarify what is meant by "and $A$ being totally real means that $\mathbb{C}P (n-1)$ intersects its image trivially."? By image do you mean $A$ applied to the elements of $\mathbb{C}P (n-1)$ inside $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$?

Comment: @PaulCusson Yes. I mean by the action of $A$ on the Grassmannian of planes.

Comment: When $n$ is odd then it doesn't matter if $A$ has odd determinant, becase $-A$ then has positive determinant and acts the same on the Grassmannian. And when $n$ is odd then the (mod $2$) self-intersection number is indeed non-zero; you can see this by calculating the mod $2$ Euler class (= Stiefel-Whitney class $w_{2n-2}$) of the normal bundle of the complex projective space in the Grassmannian.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie actually the determinant of $A$ and $-A$ is the same because the action is on $\mathbb{C}^n=\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. But you are right in any case the answer to the question is no.

Comment: But my argument by characteristic classes does not prove it in the negative determinant case.

Answer (score 3):

I argue that being totally real reduces to a problem about polynomials.

In OP's identification of $\Bbb{R}^{2n}$ with $\Bbb{C}^n$, multiplication by ${\rm{i}}$ amounts to
$J:=\begin{bmatrix}
O_n & -I_n\\
I_n & O_n
\end{bmatrix}_{2n\times 2n}$.
Now let's see how $A$ can fail to be "totally real". This means that there exists a non-zero vector $v\in\Bbb{R}^{2n}$ for which $AJv\in{\rm{Span}}\{Av,JAv\}$, i.e. the image under $A$ of the complex line in $\Bbb{C}^n$ determined by $v$ is invariant under multiplication by ${\rm{i}}$. Write $v\in\Bbb{R}^{2n}$ as
$v=\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2
\end{bmatrix}$
where $v_1,v_2\in\Bbb{R}^n$, and $A$ as
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
A_1 & A_2\\
A_3 & A_4
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $A_i$'s are $n\times n$ matrices. Then one can easily check that $AJv\in{\rm{Span}}\{Av,JAv\}$ amounts to the existence of scalars $\lambda,\mu\in\Bbb{R}$ for which
$$
-A_1v_2+A_2v_1=\lambda(A_1v_1+A_2v_2)-\mu(A_3v_1+A_4v_2),\\
-A_3v_2+A_4v_1=\lambda(A_3v_1+A_4v_2)+\mu(A_1v_1+A_2v_2).
$$
These equations can be written as
$$
(\lambda A_1-\mu A_3-A_2)v_1=(-\lambda A_2+\mu A_4-A_1)v_2,\\
(\lambda A_3+\mu A_1-A_4)v_1=-(\lambda A_4+\mu A_2+A_3)v_2.
$$
Notice that it is impossible for both
$$
\det(-\lambda A_2+\mu A_4-A_1),\det(\lambda A_4+\mu A_2+A_3)\in
\Bbb{R}[\lambda,\mu]
$$
to be identically zero.
Because then there should exist non-zero vectors $w,w'\in\Bbb{R}^n$
with $A_2w=A_4w=A_1w=\mathbf{0}$ and
$A_4w'=A_2w'=A_3w'=\mathbf{0}$. But then
$A^{\rm{T}}\begin{bmatrix}
w\\
w'
\end{bmatrix}=\mathbf{0}$, contradicting the assumption that $A$ is non-singular. WLOG, suppose
$\det(-\lambda A_2+\mu A_4-A_1)\not\equiv 0$. When
$-\lambda A_2+\mu A_4-A_1$ is invertible, one can solve the first equation for $v_2$. Substituting in the second equation, one should have
$$
\small
\left((\lambda A_3+\mu A_1-A_4)+
(\lambda A_4+\mu A_2+A_3)(-\lambda A_2+\mu A_4-A_1)^{-1}
(\lambda A_1-\mu A_3-A_2)\right)v_1=\mathbf{0}.
$$
Therefore, assuming that $\det(-\lambda A_2+\mu A_4-A_1)\not\equiv 0$,
then $A$ is not totally real iff the rational function
$$
\small
\det\left((\lambda A_3+\mu A_1-A_4)+
(\lambda A_4+\mu A_2+A_3)(-\lambda A_2+\mu A_4-A_1)^{-1}
(\lambda A_1-\mu A_3-A_2)\right)\in\Bbb{R}(\lambda,\mu)
$$
vanishes at a point of $\Bbb{R}^2$.

One possible way to show that $A$ cannot be totally real when $n$ is odd is to show that the function above should have a zero. One approach is to analyze its sign as $\lambda\to\pm\infty$ but $\mu$ is fixed.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your argument that $$
-A_1v_2+A_2v_1\in{\rm{Span}}\{A_1v_1+A_2v_2,A_3v_1+A_4v_2\},\\
-A_3v_2+A_4v_1\in{\rm{Span}}\{A_3v_1+A_4v_2,A_1v_1+A_2v_2\}. 
$$ Aren't the coefficients for the first Span the same for the second one?

Comment: @SA Correct, let me edit my answer.

Comment: your condition is $$\begin{bmatrix}
-A_1 v_2 +A_1 v_1\\
-A_3 v_2 +A_4 v_1
\end{bmatrix}\in Span \{\begin{bmatrix}
A_1 v_1 +A_2 v_2\\
A_3 v_1 +A_4 v_2
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
-A_3 v_1 -A_4 v_2\\
A_1 v_1 +A_2 v_2
\end{bmatrix}\}$$ So in your case $\lambda$ should be equal to $\mu$. Right?

Comment: @SA I rewrote the answer, thank you for pointing out the error.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Now we have to insure that the last rational function, which is defined on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus C$ where $C$ is the set that annulates $\det(-\lambda A_2+\mu A_4-A_1)$, has to vanish on $ \mathbb{R}^2\setminus C$. This function is a bit complicated to analyse (at least for me).

Comment: It is also worth noting that when $n$ is even there are situations where the last mentioned rational function never vanishes. So for a negative answer one has to use the "odd" assumption.